# Components appear on mouse hover

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have created a swings application, and what I am trying to do is, to add some components to it on button click. I am able to do this, but the problem is that, these components only appear when I hover over them. How should I make them appear as soon as the button is clicked?

```
public TransferFrom() {
    count=1;
    setTitle("Transfer Form");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 924, 571);
    pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    pane.setBackground(Color.decode("#5388BE"));
    setContentPane(pane);
    pane.setLayout(null);

    trans_pln_name= new JTextField[30];
    trans_pln_num= new JTextField[30];
    trans_amt= new JTextField[30];
    trans_inv_name= new JTextField[30];
    trans_clr=new JButton[30];
    trans_add=new JButton[30];

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Transfer Form Page");
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(240, 248, 255));
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.decode("#2c3e50"));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 40);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    pane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Action");
    lbl1.setBounds(300, 95, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lbl1);

    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Begin Date");
    lbl2.setBounds(300, 139, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lbl2);

    JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Frequency");
    lbl3.setBounds(300, 183, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lbl3);

    JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("$ or %");
    lbl4.setBounds(300, 227, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lbl4);

    JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("Future Transaction Day");
    lbl5.setBounds(300, 272, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lbl5);
    String[] action = { "Custom Transfer","Simple Transfer"};
    trans_comboBox_3 = new JComboBox(action);
    trans_comboBox_3.setSelectedIndex(0);
    trans_comboBox_3.setBounds(470, 95, 180, 33);


    pane.add(trans_comboBox_3);

    String[] freq = {"Once", "Monthly","Quarterly","Semi-Annually","Annually"}; 
    String[] dollar = { "Dollar", "Percent"};   
    trans_comboBox_4 = new JComboBox(freq);
    trans_comboBox_4.setSelectedIndex(0);
    trans_comboBox_4.setBounds(470, 183, 180, 33);
    pane.add(trans_comboBox_4);

    trans_comboBox_1 = new JComboBox(dollar);
    trans_comboBox_1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    trans_comboBox_1.setBounds(470, 227, 180, 33);
    pane.add(trans_comboBox_1);

    trans_comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
    for(int i=1;i<29;i++)
    {
        trans_comboBox_2.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    trans_comboBox_2.setSelectedIndex(0);
    trans_comboBox_2.setBounds(470, 272, 180, 33);
    pane.add(trans_comboBox_2);


    JLabel lblMaritalStatus = new JLabel("On Future Date");
    lblMaritalStatus.setBounds(300, 315, 150, 30);
    pane.add(lblMaritalStatus);

    trans_begin = new JTextField();
    trans_begin.setColumns(10);
    trans_begin.setBounds(470, 139, 180, 33);
    pane.add(trans_begin);

    trans_future = new JTextField();
    trans_future.setColumns(10);
    trans_future.setBounds(470, 320, 180, 33);
    pane.add(trans_future);

    addItem();
    pane.revalidate();

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Create Test Case");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(470, 800, 180, 33);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*assignXML();
        System.out.println(XML);
        XMLPath=new String[10];
        XMLPath[0]="C:\\Users\\paranja\\Desktop\\UI\\"+main_test_num.getText()+".xml";
        File fileName = new File(XMLPath[0] );
        if(fileName.exists())
        {
            actionDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getContentPane(),
                    "Replace existing file?");
            if (actionDialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                return;
        }
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

            out.write(XML);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        CreateGroovyAndUploadXML create=new CreateGroovyAndUploadXML();
        create.CreateGroovy(XMLPath);
             */}
    });
    pane.add(btnNewButton);



}

private void addItem() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    pane.revalidate();
    trans_pln_num[count]=new JTextField();
    trans_pln_num[count].setBounds(50, (300+count*100), 100, 50);
    trans_pln_num[count].setColumns(10);
    trans_pln_num[count].setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Plan Number"));
    pane.add(trans_pln_num[count]);

    trans_pln_name[count]=new JTextField();
    trans_pln_name[count].setBounds(200, (300+count*100), 100, 50);
    trans_pln_name[count].setColumns(10);
    trans_pln_name[count].setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Plan Name"));
    pane.add(trans_pln_name[count]);

    trans_inv_name[count]=new JTextField();
    trans_inv_name[count].setBounds(350, (300+count*100), 200, 50);
    trans_inv_name[count].setColumns(10);
    trans_inv_name[count].setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Investment Name"));
    pane.add(trans_inv_name[count]);

    trans_amt[count]=new JTextField();
    trans_amt[count].setBounds(600, (300+count*100), 200, 50);
    trans_amt[count].setColumns(10);
    trans_amt[count].setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Amount"));
    pane.add(trans_amt[count]);

    trans_clr[count]=new JButton("Clear");
    trans_clr[count].setBounds(850, (300+count*100), 50, 50);
    pane.add(trans_clr[count]);

    trans_add[count]=new JButton("+");
    trans_add[count].setBounds(950, (300+count*100), 50, 50);
    trans_add[count].addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            count=count+1;
            addItem();
        }
    });
    pane.add(trans_add[count]);
    pane.revalidate();

}
```

Comment: `revalidate` is useless to you as you've decided to do without a the layout manager.  `revalidate` simply updates all the layout information for the container and it's children.  Try using `repaint` instead and a layout manager

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Consider using a `JTable` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am pretty new to Swings. For now, I haven't used layout manager. But the repaint command actually helped! Thanks!

Comment: Now is the time to get started with layout managers - [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I'll try using JTable as well! Thanks for your inputs!